# kotlin data-classes without kotlin-stdlib maven dependency

Tags: maven, kotlin

we have a kotlin-microservice that needs to expose a maven-artifact that defines all DataTransferObjects that are required/emitted by that microservice (e.g. kotlin data-classes that represent events published to the event-bus).

client of that microservice is however a pure java application which shall depend on this kotlin-DTO-maven-artifact but **not** transitively get the kotlin-stdlib or any other kotlin-specific dependencies injected.

can we provide the kotlin-DTOs without introducing any kotlin-dependency?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and the most reasonable for me would be to create those DTOs as Java classes since the Kotlin is compatible with such classes

You don't need for this any additional tools or tricks. Inside this artifact you can easily use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to not write plenty of boiler plate code